# difference in scanf parameters

Tags: c, scanf

When I write a program, I don't give attention about parameters of `scanf`.
What is the difference between:

```
scanf("%d %d", &x,&y);
```

and

```
scanf("%d%d", &x,&y);
```

note the space between `%d`s.
I tried on my pc, but I can't see the difference.

Also, what about `%c` instead of `%d` - what is the difference between

```
scanf("%c %c", &x,&y);
```

and

```
scanf("%c%c", &x,&y);
```

Can you give me useful examples to understand this stupid thing?

Comment: You should read [a good `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: sorry, maybe I have wrote a bad example: 
the difference between scanf("%c %c", &x,  &y); and scanf("%c%c", &x, &y);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case they both result in the same whether you put a space between or not :)

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf):

> All conversion specifiers other than [, c, and n consume and discard all leading whitespace characters (determined as if by calling isspace) before attempting to parse the input. These consumed characters do not count towards the specified maximum field width.
>
> The conversion specifiers that do not consume leading whitespace, such as %c, can be made to do so by using a whitespace character in the format string:

```
scanf("%d", &a);
scanf(" %c", &c); // ignore the endline after %d, then read a char
```

So your example: `scanf("%c%c", &x, &y);` will not skip whitespace.
If you input `a b` followed by enter it will read `a` and a whitespace.
On the other hand if you input `ab` it will read a and b as you wanted.

In the example: `scanf("%c %c", &x, &y);`, if you input `a` and hit enter, it will ignore the newline, and let you enter the other character.

Comment: @linofex No, the `"%c"` format doesn't skip leading white-space.

Comment: sorry, maybe I have wrote a bad example: the difference between scanf("%c %c", &x, &y); and scanf("%c%c", &x, &y);

Comment: @linofex: Adding the space makes sure your program can handle input like this: `x<enter>y<enter>`. spaces in format strings tell `scanf` to ignore any whitespace chars in between the chars (including new lines)

Comment: tried in my pc. and in the case with %c there is the difference: with a space in scanf parameters even if I enter spaces the two variables don't eat space! Instead with scanf("%c%c".....) the second %c eat a space or a newline. right?

Comment: You didn't answer the first question (what is the difference between `"%d %d"` and `"%d%d"`). The answer is "nothing".

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%d %d", &x, &y)` will eat the space (if any) after first integer is read and then read the second integer, while `scanf("%d%d", &x, &y)` will ignore whitespace while reading two integers. However both produce same results when run.

Comment: Your answer is confusing. You explain the first two `scanf`s in a somewhat different way as if there was any difference between them.

Comment: `scanf` *needs* to *eat*!

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour [Badly](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WizardNeedsFoodBadly)!

Answer (score 1):

A format directive that matches whitespace (e.g. anything for which `isspace` returns true) causes as much whitespace as possible to be read and discarded from the stream (`stdin`, in this case).

This process is required prior to the `%d` format directive translating digits, anyway; that is, the `%d` directive will read and discard as much whitespace as possible, and then read and translate a sign and/or sequence of decimal digits to an `int`.

In summary, with or without the whitespace directive, the functionality of these two statements is identical; the whitespace directive is superfluous in this case.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it is clean and useful!I edited my question changing the same problem with %c instead that %d. In this case there is difference.